# Lottie Animation: Stop Loop but wait until animation has finished

Tags: ios, swift, animation, lottie

Im currently working on animating a button with different animations in Swift with Lottie.

What I need is a way to stop a loop but only when the animation reached the end and would repeat itself. In that moment I want to be able to chime in and replace the animation with another non-looping one, so that it looks like a fluent transition from the looping animation to the other. The reason for this is, that I wait for the completion of fetching data over the network while looping the animation.

It did it the other way around to come into the looping animation like this:

```swift
func animate(animation: Animation?, endIn loop: Animation?) {
    self.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
    self.animationView.isHidden = false
    self.animationView.animation = animation
    self.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
    self.animationView.play { _ in
        self.animationView.animation = loop
        self.animationView.loopMode = .loop
        self.animationView.play()
    }
}
```

Maybe someone else already implemented such transtion, I'd appreciate any help with this.

Edit: I tried to to it this way and then when fetching completed just called `self.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce`

```swift
func animate(startAnimation: Animation?,
             transitionTo loop: Animation?,
             endAnimation: Animation?,
             image: UIImage?) {
    self.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
    self.animationView.isHidden = false
    self.animationView.animation = startAnimation
    self.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
    self.animationView.play { _ in
        self.animationView.animation = loop
        self.animationView.loopMode = .loop
        self.animationView.play { _ in
            self.animationView.animation = endAnimation
            self.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
            self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

I found a working though bad solution by starting the loop by upper function and then calling this to end it:

```swift
func stopLoopAndTranstion(to animation: Animation?, endIn image: UIImage?) {
    guard let animation = animation else {
        return
    }

    if self.animationView.realtimeAnimationProgress > 0.95 {
        self.animationView.stop()
        self.animationView.animation = animation
        self.animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
        self.animationView.play()
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            self.stopLoopAndTranstion(to: animation, endIn: image)
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is to check the animationProgress and as soon as it hits a certain progress I stop and replace the animation.
I rather consider this a hack than a solution. Everytime I trigger this function the CPU Usage goes up by 2-3% until the animation is replaced.
While those 2-3% can be neglectable, I'm not satisfied yet and am still looking for a cleaner way to achieve something like this.

Comment: Wait for the duration remaining in the animation instead of an arbitrary time?

Answer (score 7):

You can use one of the `play(fromProgress...)` API's that `Lottie` provides

```
animationView.play(
    fromProgress: animationView.currentProgress,
    toProgress: 1,
    loopMode: .playOnce,
    completion: { [weak self] completed in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            self.stopLoopAndTranstion(to: animation, endIn: image)
        }
    }
)
```

this will ensure that your current animation will finish and in `completion` block you can do your finishing work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to set repeatcount at 0